# Using a wiki as a central development project repository

Tags: svn, integration, wiki, projects, bugzilla

I have played with the idea of using a wiki (MediaWiki) to centralize all project information for a development project.  This was done using extensions that pull information from SVN (using [SVNKit](http://svnkit.com/)) and by linking to Bugzilla to extract work assigned to a developer or work remaining for a release.

Examples:

```
<bugzilla type="summary" user="richard.tasker@gmail.com" />
```

would return a summary

[image: Bugzilla Summary]

```
<bugzilla type="status" status="ASSIGNED" product="SCM BEPPI" />
```

would return

[image: Bugzilla Status]

Do you think that this would be useful?  If so then what other integrations would you think would be valuable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be extremly useful. Depending on the size of a project team members come and go. And a wiki is a good tool to keep the history and the "spirit" of a project available to new team members. I did that in many projects, and though the projects were already finished, all the informations are available.

One more idea: also try to integrate meeting schedules, minutes etc. If your team communicates via IM, try to integrate a log of the conversations.

Answer (score 5):

Of course it's useful, there are already ready-made packages for this kind of project-overviews (like http://trac.edgewall.org/).

If possible, I'd integrate any existing CI-engine into the wiki, so that you have a complete overview over the current progress and your project's health.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the mediawiki extension I've created @ http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:BugzillaReports.  I'm getting a lot of great feedback that this is hitting a sweet spot - it allows you to bring bugzilla reports in line into mediawiki documents and create standard aggregated reports.

Answer (score 0):

The other classic integration would be your source code repository, e.g. svn, or cvs. [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is an existing product that does exactly this - it combines a wiki, custom bug tracker, and integrates nicely with svn.

Answer (score 0):

The other integration I worked on was integrating to MS Project but the integration was a little messy requiring upload of .mpp files and then using MPXJ to extract project information from the .mpp file

The result was OK I suppose

```
<project file="AOZA_BEPPI_Billing_Project_Plan_v0.2.mpp" type="list" user="Martin" />
```

[image: MS Project Integ]